# ProgressBar(s) (Horizontal) not showing progress of (int)long

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have an app on the market and am adding a few horizontal ProgressBars. The first bar updates and displays correctly, no problems with it whatsoever. The second bar (identical code) is there, but showing no progress despite setting max and progress. I have tried invalidating (and postInvalidate()) the views with no luck. Here is some snippage:

**Layout.xml:**

```
       <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStorageAName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/storage_a" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStorageA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="N/A" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progBarStorageA"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/progbar_bg"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progbar_bg" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStorageBName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/storage_b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStorageB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="N/A" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progBarStorageB"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/progbar_bg"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progbar_bg" />
        </TableRow>
```

And here is the code that I use to setProgress and Max on ProgressBars, inside of a `Fragment`

**Fragment.java:**

```
progA = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progBarStorageA);
    progB = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progBarStorageB);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        kitKatWorkaround();
    } else if (storageInfoList.size() > 0) {

        tvStorageAName.setText(storageInfoList.get(0).path);

        long usedA = StorageUtils.getUsedSpace(storageInfoList.get(0).path);
        long totalA = StorageUtils
                .getTotalSpace(storageInfoList.get(0).path);

        devStorageA = StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(usedA, true) + "/"
                + StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(totalA, true);

        progA.setMax((int) totalA);
        progA.setProgress((int) usedA);

        if (storageInfoList.size() > 1) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
                    && !storageInfoList.get(0).internal) {
                kitKatWorkaround();
            }
            tvStorageBName.setText(storageInfoList.get(1).path);

            long usedB = StorageUtils
                    .getUsedSpace(storageInfoList.get(1).path)
                    + (StorageUtils.getUsedSpace("system/"));
            long totalB = StorageUtils
                    .getTotalSpace(storageInfoList.get(1).path);

            devStorageB = StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(usedB, true)
                    + "/" + StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(totalB, true);

            progB.setMax((int) totalB);
            progB.setProgress((int) usedB);
        } else {

            tvStorageBName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvStorageB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            devStorageB = "N/A";
        }
    } else {
        devStorageA = "N/A";

        tvStorageBName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvStorageB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        devStorageB = "N/A";
    }
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void kitKatWorkaround() {

    tvStorageA = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvStorageA);
    tvStorageB = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvStorageB);

    File[] sdCards = getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            .getExternalCacheDirs();

    if (sdCards.length > 0
            && sdCards[0] != null
            && Environment.getStorageState(sdCards[0]).equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        File sdCard1 = sdCards[0];

        tvStorageAName.setText(sdCard1.getAbsolutePath()
                .replace(
                        "Android/data/" + getActivity().getPackageName()
                                + "/cache", ""));

        long usedA = StorageUtils.getUsedSpace(sdCard1.getAbsolutePath());
        long totalA = StorageUtils.getTotalSpace(sdCard1.getAbsolutePath());

        devStorageA = StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(usedA, true) + "/"
                + StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(totalA, true);

        progA.setMax((int) totalA);
        progA.setProgress((int) usedA);
    } else {
        devStorageA = "N/A";
    }

    if (sdCards.length > 1
            && sdCards[1] != null
            && Environment.getStorageState(sdCards[1]).equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File sdCard2 = sdCards[1];

        tvStorageBName.setText(sdCard2.getAbsolutePath()
                .replace(
                        "Android/data/" + getActivity().getPackageName()
                                + "/cache", ""));

        long usedB = StorageUtils.getUsedSpace(sdCard2.getAbsolutePath());
        long totalB = StorageUtils.getTotalSpace(sdCard2.getAbsolutePath());

        devStorageB = StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(usedB, true) + "/"
                + StorageUtils.getReadableFileSize(totalB, true);

        progB.setMax((int) totalB);
        progB.setProgress((int) usedB);

    } else {
        tvStorageBName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvStorageB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        devStorageB = "N/A";
    }

    tvStorageA.setText(devStorageA);
    tvStorageB.setText(devStorageB);
}
```

This is the result (I feel a noobish mistake somewhere), any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time
[image: This is the result]

**EDIT:** Now, I have downloaded a file and have 25Gb/27.5Gb on first storage. Neither progressBar is showing progress now. I'm lost on this for now... I can confirm with logcat (in bytes):

```
06-19 23:56:00.729: D/StorageUtils(24282): /proc/mounts
06-19 23:56:00.739: D/Storage(24282): 24006316032/27480944640
06-19 23:56:00.739: D/Storage(24282): 15548907520/15923150848
```

**EDIT2:** This seems to work when it wants to. I have tested on several devices with different storage scenarios, some show perfectly, some not at all.

Comment: is usedB has a value when updating?

Comment: yes, the same value in the text without letters. `long usedB = StorageUtils
                    .getUsedSpace(storageInfoList.get(1).path)
                    + (StorageUtils.getUsedSpace("system/"));
            long totalB = StorageUtils
                    .getTotalSpace(storageInfoList.get(1).path);` which gets 15.5/15.9 on my device currently as seen in pic

Comment: 2 on my device. The sizes are accurate for each device iv'e tested, and paths are valid. Returned sizes of sdCard(s) are accurate, but the progressBar does not display it. If there is not a 2nd path (sdcard), the 2nd set of views are set to invisible. Could the max and min of a `Long` as seen in logcat too big for progressBar?

Answer (score 7):

I'd wager that it's related to an integer overflow.

Your max value is 27 480 944 640 while the Integer Max Value is 2 147 483 647. Since the Progress Bar works with Integers, it's probably doing weird stuff.

You should normalize your values for your progress bar.

```
progB.setMax(100);
progB.setProgress((int) ((((float)usedB) / totalB)*100));
```

This should give you a close enough representation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it is still showing the same results :( I agree with you though, should I divide `usedB/1024` or something?

Comment: Actually there was an error on my part, forgot to multiply by 100. Dividing by 1024 won't be enough, you really have to normalize you value and not just divide it by a constant.

Comment: I understand, and this should work... Still nothing though. I appreciate your help

Comment: @MattMatt Your division will _always_ produce `0`. Cast `usedB` or `totalB` to `float` for accurate results. Here: `progB.setProgress((int) ((((float)usedB) / totalB)*100))`;

Comment: Beautiful, you are correct @Vikram. Thank you both, now who is the winner lol?

Comment: @MattMatt PeekaySwitch is :).

Comment: Thanks @Vikram, my napkin coding still needs some work

Comment: @PeekaySwitch Your napkin coding is just fine :) You did solve the problem. Please don't forget to edit your answer for future googlers.